# Discord.js v13 return in message collector doesn't stop collecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I try to create a "Setup" command with `message.channel.createMessageCollector()` in [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) v13. I want the user to type `quit` to cancel/abort the command. I am trying with this code using a `return` inside the collector doesn't stop it:

```js
const filter = (m) => {
  return m.author.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
  filter,
  max: 5,
  time: 1000 * 20,
});

collector.on("collect", (collect) => {
  if (collect.content.toLowerCase() === "quit") return message.reply("Bye!"); // The return is doesn't work
});
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `return` statement won't stop the collector. It just makes the rest of the code inside that function not to run. But, if there is a new incoming message, the callback function gets executed again.

However, you can use the [`Collector#stop()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector?scrollTo=stop) method that stops the collector and emits the `end` event. You can also add a reason the collector is ending.

Check out the code below:

```js
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;

const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
  filter,
  max: 5,
  time: 1000 * 20,
});

collector.on('collect', (collected) => {
  if (collected.content.toLowerCase() === 'quit') {
    // collector stops and emits the end event
    collector.stop('user cancelled');
    // although the collector stopped this line is still executed
    return message.reply('Bye!');
  }

  // this line only runs if the above if statement is false
  message.reply(`You said _"${collected.content}"_`);
});

// listening for the end event
collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
  // reason is the one you passed above with the stop() method
  message.reply(`I'm no longer collecting messages. Reason: ${reason}`);
});
```

[image]